# why is rename() not working on the next line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and was working with the diamonds table in ggplot2. I renamed a column using rename() but didn't get updated in the next line when I tried to find the mean using the new name. It would be helpful if someone could guide me. I know this question might sound a bit stupid. I just want to know what am I doing incorrectly?

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
rename(diamonds, carat_new = carat)
summarise(diamonds, mean_carat = mean(carat_new))
```

the console says:

```
Error in `summarise()`:
ℹ In argument: `mean_carat = mean(carat_new)`.
Caused by error:
! object 'carat_new' not found
```

Comment: I think you just forgot to assign the updated  column back to the table:  diamonds_renamed <- rename(diamonds, carat_new = carat)

Answer (score 1):

`carat_new` is not found because you did not update `diamonds`.

One option is update `diamonds`:

```
> diamonds <- rename(diamonds, carat_new = carat)
> summarise(diamonds, mean_carat = mean(carat_new))
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  mean_carat
       <dbl>
1      0.798
```

Another option would be using the pipe operator:

```
diamonds %>% 
  rename(carat_new = carat) %>% 
  summarise(mean_carat = mean(carat_new))
```